# Changing text color onclick and change back for other items

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I found this in another question/answer and modified it... but it still doesn't work. I'm a js-noob, so.. could someone please help me out? It's probably simple...

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('change').onclick = changeColor;   
    function changeColor() {
        document.body.style.color = "red";
        return false;
    }   
</script>

<div id="myid" onclick="changeColor(this); return false;">Hello Here !!</div><br>
<div id="myid2" onclick="changeColor(this); return false;">Hello There !!</div><br>
```

My issue is: When I run this, both should have black color. When I click on the first, ONLY THAT one should turn red. If after that I click on the second one, the first one should be black again and only the second one red...
How do I do this? (jquery would be welcome as well, if that has a solution...)

Thanks!

Comment: first, you do a getElementById on the the 'change' id, and there is no element with this is id in your html. Then, You call the changeColor function on your onClick with "this) as parameter, but the changeColor function does not handle any parameter (blablacanworkblabla). Finally, it is a bad practice to put handlers in your inline html.

Comment: Also, everything @roselan said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you Edwin. I did some googling and fiddled around with something I found and it does exactly what I want to do. Sorry for the confusion.. I picked the divs and if I could get that to work, then I would implement it for my li's.. 
Anyway, the solution is:

javascript part:

```
function switchColors(element)  
{  
links=document.getElementsByTagName("li") ;  
for (var i = 0 ; i < links.length ; i ++)  
links.item(i).style.color = 'black' ;  
element.style.color='orange' ;  
}
```

and the html stuff that needed the color change:

```
<ul>  
<li onclick="switchColors(this);">Link 1</li>  
<li onclick="switchColors(this);">Link 2</li>  
<li onclick="switchColors(this);">Link 3</li>  
</ul>
```

Comment: Just ran this...this code doesn't work at all. Also, you completely ignored the recommendations in my answer and in @roselan's comments when you used this code.

Comment: It works fine for me. The javascript is not in the header, but in a script at the bottom of the page... at least, that's how I set it up and it works.
As far as "ignoring" goes.. I took it as "the code given is a piece of [fill in the blank] and you'll have to do a ton of changes". Since I wanted to use li's instead anyways, I looked for another solution instead, edited that and came up with I posted above.
As far as using predefined rules.. do you mean changing classes thru js instead of changing the "li" (in this case)? As far as I know I can't do what I want to do by css alone...

Comment: Yes, as in using jQuery's `$(obj).addClass("red")` followed by `$(obj).removeClass("black")`, or by using the native `obj.class = "red"` to toggle between colors, where the CSS is `.red { color: #f00; }` and `.black { color: #000; }`. Alternatively, you might also want to check out `$(obj).toggleClass("red"); $(obj).toggleClass("black");`.

Comment: A couple more things...the stuff you usually find on the web are usually examples meant to give complete newcomers to the language an introduction, and so use some terrible, terrible coding methods. My guess is that this is one of them. In addition, if you want a faster reply from me, tag me in your post/comment with `@Edwin`.

Comment: But with this case it is not possible that the link 1 is the default black color when arriving on the page instead?

Answer (score 4):

Here's your [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/64QpR/5/).

It's not the best, but considering the mistakes you made copying the code, you might want to check out [Wikiversity's page on Beginning JavaScript](http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Basic_JavaScript), as well as their [challenges](http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Web_Design/JavaScript_Challenges).

Also, a list of errors in the code you copied, so you can avoid these problems again:

1. The first line of script gets an element with ID 'change'. No such ID exists in your HTML.
2. `document.body` does not return a valid JavaScript object with which you can access `.style.color`.
3. `changeColor()` does not accept any arguments, so you should not be calling it with `changeColor(this)`.
4. Do not use inline DOM. I.e., do not use the `onclick` attribute in the HTML. HTML is meant for layout, not scripting.
5. (Added by @roselan in the comments below) Instead of using $.css or JavaScript's native .style, use predefined CSS style rules and switch elements' classes to get the desired effect. (an example of this practice can be found in the solution.)

And most importantly,
**layout should remain in HTML, scripting in JavaScript, and styling in CSS.**

Comment: 5. instead of using $.css or native .style, switch classes with corresponding css rules. (all style in css files, all code in js files, and all html in html files)